# Read latest inserted / updated 100 records from HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a requirement to read the latest inserted/updated rows from HBase table which has the total number of rows around 15 million.

I see few answers in this forum suggesting to use TIMERANGE in Scan, but using TIMERANGE in Scan we can only get the 'latest' state of the record at a certain point in time.

Could you please advise how we can retrieve the last inserted/updated records. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve last inserted rows, put reverse_time_stamp in prefix of rowkey. So latest records will come first in your scan. In case of update delete old row and insert new row with new reverse_time_stamp. In case of update if you are ok with cost of delete and insert, this will work for you as it is making your fetching very efficient. You are going to scan only records which are necessary.

Comment: This solution would can be considered while designing the table. in the above case data is already existed and has millions of rows.